# Cannot pass ampersand and hash sign in MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("LoadFilter", "Contact", new { filterType = (int)FilterContactBy.Name }, new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "ShowProgrees", OnSuccess = "HideProgress" }))
{
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactFilter.FilterValue, new { placeholder = "Enter a name" })                                                                                                      
      <input type="submit" class="link submit green" value="Add Filter" />                            
 }
```

As quite obvious, the `ShowProgress` and `HideProgress` method do nothing but show and hide a loader gif.

The method at backend is

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult LoadFilter(ContactListModel filter, int filterType=0, Boolean isAllFilterApply=true)
 {
     if (filter != null)
     {
         // process here
     }
 }
```

It works fine if I enter anything, for example

```
hi
test
me & you
contact #1
contact #1 and me
```

**BUT**
When I enter `&#` together in any from error occurs. The loader gif just keeps moving and the code on Controller is never hit.

Also, in Chrome console, it shows `500 Internal Server Error` (and so does Firefox!).

**My Solution**
I tried `escape` and `enocodeURIComponent` but it didn't worked. Here's the method I tried

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(o, org, xhr) { 
  if (org.url.indexOf('/Contact/LoadFilter?filterType=') > -1) {
    // console.log(org.data[0].value);
    org.data[0].value = encodeURIComponent(org.data[0].value);
    // console.log(org.data[0].value);    
  }
});
```

The output (in console)

```
&#
%26%23
```

When instead of `encodeURIComponent` I used `escape`, the output was same

```
&#
%26%23
```

But it still doesn't hit the method on controller. Can anyone please help me to get a solution, and more importantly, tell me *why* is this occurring in the first place?

**ps**
Please don't ask me that what is the use of inputting `&#` in a contact filter, or to remove these and tell client this is not a valid input. I can't do that, so please don't advice that.

**Update**
Is anyone even reading this fully? I am not asking that *how can I decode*. **NO**. Please read the full question before marking it as duplicate or marking it for close.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I got this.

I created `Application_BeginRequest` in `Global.asax` in the code like this..

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var httpApp = (HttpApplication)sender;
            Debug.Write(httpApp);
        }
```

I sat a breakpoint of `httpApp` and then in the `watch` window, checked for `httpApp.Request` and found that it was there. It said `(something I don't remember right now) threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException'`.

So, I got that the error was because of this, so on the method `LoadFilter`, I just added the attribute `ValidateInput(false)`, and it's working

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
 public ActionResult LoadFilter(ContactListModel filter, int filterType=0, Boolean isAllFilterApply=true)
 {
   // process here
 }
```

Though, I do have to check for sql injection in here because we are building up a dynamic query from the input we receive.

Answer (score -4):

Use

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("url")
```

Comment: Did you read the question? It's not even hitting the action on controller page. I know I can use `UrlDecode`, but for that first it have to hit the action right? And that was the question.